# Set form position with .offset() relative to dynamic table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, offset

I would like to position a form at the same coordinates of a dynamic  upon a click event of the  element, however the form does not position at the desired coordinates. I am able to position the form when triggering the event on a static element but not on the dynamic table element, which makes me think my problem has something to do with the dynamic table.

**CSS**

```
.form {
   width:600px;
   background-color:rgb(102,153,153);
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#table2').on("click", ".topic", function (event) {

    var getid = event.target.id;
    var mouseX = event.pageX;
    var mouseY = event.pageY;

    console.log(mouseX + " " + mouseY); //shows coordinates

    $('div.form').show();
    $('div.form').offset({
        left: mouseX,
        top: mouseY
    });
    $('div.form').attr('style', 'position:absolute');
})
```

**HTML**

**JS to build table**
    $('#table2').append('' +  topic + '\
    ' + posttimestamp +'\
    ' + post_txt + '\
    ' + postuser + '' + breed + ' \
    +1-1\
    ' + votes + '');

Now I don't think the problem is the table because I am able to position a

element at the same coordinates of a click event on '#drop' and '#add'.

Comment: Does this click handler even trigger when you click? Not sure why it wouldn't work otherwise!

Comment: Can I assume the `.topic` is a class assigned to some elements within the `#table2`? so the form will be displayed only when a `.topic` element is clicked.

Comment: it would be very helpful if you add the html markup in your OP. I guess your problem relates to `html` because i don't see any faults in your code!

Answer (score 0):

Here is concept that may work for you.

For the **HTML**, begin by wrapping your table and form in a common block container.
This is not totally necessary but it is a simple way of illustrating the concept.

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
<table id="table2">
    <tr>
        <td>a <b class="topic">topic</b> is here</td>
        <td class="topic">a topic cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="topic">a topic cell</td>
        <td>more content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some content</td>
        <td class="topic">a topic cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="form">
    <p>This is your Form.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

For the **CSS**:

```css
.form {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color:rgb(102, 153, 153);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
}
.table-wrap {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
}
#table2 {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
#table2 td {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
#table2 .topic {
    background-color: pink;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The table consists of a few table cells, some of which have the class `.topic`. Note that within the first cell, I have an inline element with the `.topic` class.

The `.table-wrap` container is positioned relative and the `.form` is positioned absolutely. Since both the `.form` and `#table2` are positioned with respect to the same parent block, their offsets are measured from the same origin.

The **jQuery** is:

```js
$('.table-wrap').on("click", ".topic", function (event) {
    var getid = event.target.id;
    var mouseX = event.pageX;
    var mouseY = event.pageY;

    console.log(mouseX + " " + mouseY); //shows coordinates

    $('div.form').show();
    $('div.form').offset({
        left: mouseX,
        top: mouseY
    });
})
```

Essentially, set the top/left offset like you did and show the form.  Your JavaScript was correct, but the CSS positioning needed help.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/5XCQR/

**PS: About Dynamic Tables**

I created the form element explicitly but you could create it using jQuery's DOM manipulation functions.

The trick is to bind the jQuery action to an element that is native to the DOM
(not dynamically created using JavaScript).  In this case, I opted to bind the actin to `.table-wrap`, which should be present in the original DOM.  The table could then be created dynamically and inserted in the wrapper without breaking the action binding.

Comment: Thanks much. Let me work through this and I will let you know.